# Is it possible to refer to Rg in With Rg

Tags: vba, excel, with-statement

Is it possible to refer to Rg in With Rg? I have a long with statement and I would like to pass the range specified in the With statement as a parameter. Is this possible?

```
With rg.OffSet(0, -1).Resize(ColumnSize:=1)

    'set conditional format
    Call SetConditionalFormat(rg.OffSet(0, -1).Resize(ColumnSize:=1))

    'I tried this but it didn't work
    Call SetConditionalFormat(.range)

End With
```

Sure I could simply repeat the `rg.OffSet(0, -1).Resize(ColumnSize:=1)` or assign it to a variable, but I'm curious if such a thing exists as referring to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case with `Range` object you could use:

```
Call SetConditionalFormat(.Cells)
```

it's not a self-referring, but could help you to operate with target object.

Comment: I'll take this; I suppose there is not such a thing as a self reference to the With object.

Comment: @D_Bester: No, there is not.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen prettier code but it works ;)

```
With rg.Offset(0, -1).Resize(ColumnSize:=1)

    Call SetConditionalFormat(.Parent.Range(.Address))

End With
```

Comment: it's better to specify sheet to: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(.Parent.Name).Range(.Address)`. Btw good answer:)

Comment: @D_Bester, or just `Call SetConditionalFormat(.Cells)`

Comment: @simoco - Thanks, I have deliberately omitted the sheet because I did not know if he had a variable for it but sure it's always better to explicitly specify the sheet.  Btw yours is cleaner than mine, you should put it as answer.